# Django 2.0 + Postgres heroku migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to run a `Django` application with `Postgres` in `Heroku`. I have created an app for the application but the problem is that the app migrations are not being applied in `Heroku`. I am using the [heroku starter](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template) base template and have committed the necessary migration files.

When I run 
`heroku run python manage.py migrate`, the first set of migrations apply:

```
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
blah blah blah
```

But when I run it the second time it gives me the the output

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

If I specify the app using
`heroku run python manage.py migrate phone` I get the error `CommandError: No migrations present for: phone`

In my local development, I have an app called `phone` that I have added to the `settings.py` and can run local migrations.

Comment: If you run `migrate` once, why would you run them a 2nd time if they are already applied? Also have you ran `makemigrations`?

Comment: As you can see in the operations to perform:, my custom app is not listed. Yes I have run makemigrations and migrate locally and commited the files to heroku.

Comment: have you committed your changes to the `settings.py` file to the heroku repo?

Comment: yes I committed the whole project and can create a super user, log in the admin site etc. The problem is when I click on my model that I registered in the app, it says there is a programming error because the column does not exist

Comment: have you tried hooking up your local project to the postgres database and run the migrations from your local project? If this works fine, then it would just be a matter of committing and pushing the project to heroku. At least thats how I have done it before. Hope this helps!

Comment: have not tried that but is that a "hacky" way to get it working? What if I have other changes later on? Do I just keep using the heroku postgres database for the migrations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166749/discussion-between-n-ivanov-and-rgfvfk-iff).

Comment: It seems to me that the most likely explanation is that either the migrations or the settings file which includes `phone` in `INSTALLED_APPS` have not been committed and pushed to Heroku. I know you say you've committed the files to Heroku, but how have you verified this?

Comment: i have logged in to the heroku console and I can see the migrations folder and migration files inside my app. I can manually run makemigrations inside the console but when I run migrate there is an error